# Creating a timed event with shared hosting?

Tags: c#, asp.net, triggers

I'm not sure if this is possible using regular hosting plans like those from GoDaddy/Razor Hosting/DiscountASP/etc., or if I'll need a VPS (or similar).

What I'm trying to do is to either have a program run constantly and perform an activity every hour or have the program start every hour.  The program/service basically uses HttpWebRequest to get a web page's source and saves it to a SQL Server database.  Obviously I want it to run every x number of minutes to keep the content up-to-date.  I may use the program 7 times a day or I may use it every 7 months, so it can't crawl a site every time the page is visited.

On my own machine, I'd create an ASP.Net page with a thread or backgroundservice that checks the time for an hourly interval and then performs the task.  But since I'm on another machine that I have very limited access, I don't know how to go about this.  I was thinking maybe a SQL Server trigger would worked, perhaps off of system time, but I'm not sure if this would work (I'd be executing a program?).

There are lots of other ways to perform this task on my machine, but I can't do any of them b/c I don't have access to the actual system with regular hosting.  So do I have to get a VPS [or something similar] or is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to run programs/software on standard hosting plans. You will need either a VPS or Dedicated Hosting. Dedicated Hosting is preferred as some VPS plans, depending on host, still won't even allow it.

However you could do something similar with PHP, or any web language,  and then have it run as a Cron Job, which is allowed on normal hosting. Basically if you can code it into what would be a front-end page or small script (perl/python etc),then you can code it and have it run as Cron. So for example code the page, place in directory /crons then like the Cron Job to it, but just don't like anywhere else in site to it.

Comment: If your application can run on mono, a good(but affordable) VPS is linode. I use it for my website and they give you root access and all that

Comment: Thank you, I'll have to look into cron jobs; I know the command is Linux/Unix in origin, but that's about it.

Comment: @Panuvin Which command are you referring to? Cron Job? If so you can setup Cron Jobs via GoDaddy Hosting Manager. http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/3547/creating-a-basic-cron-job

Answer (score 1):

One of the best and simplest solution is Cache and feature of invalidation of cache object.

```
System.Web.HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(key,value, null, DateTime.UtcNow.AddHour(1), Cache.NoSliding, Pariority.Default, DelegateToCallWhenCacheIsInvalid);
```

Asp.Net remove value from cache in 1 hour and call your delegate method. You can do your job and put another value to cache for 1 hour. 
Notice some case:

1. in shared hosts, application shutdown if no request received in specific duration. You can send request to your host manually in code repeatedly.
2. if application shutdown or restarted, cache is recycled. You must save last run date and time to calculate correct first period after start application.
3. May be your cache removed for less memory. check reason of removing value in delegate or set priority to high.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to use Hangfire for **Recurring tasks**. It is very easy to configure and use with ASP.NET Web MVC/API though i havent actually tried that on godaddy.

Answer (score 0):

DiscountASP has a "Scheduled Task Manager" in the Control Panel: you tell it to call a page of yours once every 15 minutes or more (then you can code your activity to run within that page).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the perfect way to plan and organise the events with single minute time scheduling. Let me tell you can use the [online event registration system](https://www.eventry.com/en/Event/Event-Registration) to handle various types of functions easily.

This system has the ability to promote and manage events simultaneously, with its help you doesn't have to worry about managing the time for ticket selling or registration. Also it will gives the privilege of designing custom made event page and even tickets.

I am sure you will see the difference after implementation of this system.